# CSS - Moving an Element every time the page width changes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my project, I have a simple div that acts as a nav bar. Within this div, I have an image of a logo.

What I want is every time my page width changes, my logo position will update

I have already tried to do this with media queries, however I imagine creating a media query every time the page width changes is extremely inefficient.
Is there a way to accomplish this more efficiently?

Here is my existing code:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <img src="{% static 'spotifyLogo.png' %}" alt="Image of the spotify logo" id="spotifyLogoImage" width="197px" height="59px">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#navBar {
  border: 1px solid hsl(231, 12%, 89%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 104px;
}

#spotifyLogoImage {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 854px;
  margin-top: 23px;
}


WHOLE NAV BAR CODE:

    <div id="navBar">
        <img src="{% static 'spotifyLogo.png' %}" alt="Image of the spotify logo" id="spotifyLogoImage" width="195px" height="59px">
      </div>


    #navBar {
      border: 1px solid hsl(231, 12%, 89%);
      width: 100%;
      height: 104px;
      resize: both;
      overflow: auto
    }

    #spotifyLogoImage {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      padding-right: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Unless you want to craft media queries for every single breakpoint, your best bet is to make use of JavaScript and attach to the `scroll` event. Also, use relative units of measurement, not fixed high value pixel measurements -- this will display poorly on a narrow device.

Comment: Have you tried `#spotifyLogoImage { float: right }` instead of `{margin-left : 854px}`

Comment: I would suggest you to read through this [tutorial about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It should provide you a lot of information about positioning elements relative to your window and other elements.

Comment: @Light Hello. When I add float right, I then add a margin because I dont want the image all the way to the right. But when I resize my page, now the functionality is gone.

Comment: @Light I want the image to look like it has stayed in a fixed position when I resize my window

Comment: Use `padding-right` instead, I believe

Comment: @Light When I add padding-right onto my image element, It decreases in size. It becomes squished.

Comment: @Light I do not want my size to be effected but when applying padding-righ to the image like you mentioned, size is effected.

Comment: Is it practical for you to upload more of the navbar code? I can't recreate the resizing from the code given - I could be missing something though

Comment: @Light Yes please check my original post as I have updated it.

Comment: @Light The code there includes the whole code that functions my nav bar

Comment: https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/yLLrLZd - I can't recreate the squishing with `padding: right` you're talking about - Are the `height` and `width` properties in the `img` HTML correct?

Comment: @Light Go onto the Spotify sign up website, and when you resize the window you will see the Spotify logo moves with the screen.

Comment: @Light This is this functionality I am hoping for.

Comment: I'm unsure - As was said further up the comments I think it's worth having a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can un-approve an answer I believe, if mine is no longer helpful

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your *CSS* `margin-left` you were trying to right-align your image - So, you could use `float: right` instead, so it dynamically updates with the it's parent div

```css
#navBar {
  border: 1px solid hsl(231, 12%, 89%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 104px;
  
  /* Just for demo */
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto
}

#spotifyLogoImage {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Image of the spotify logo" id="spotifyLogoImage" width="75px" height="75px">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very sufficient.